# PDF of $Y=X(X-1)$ when $X$ has a piecewise PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have to solve the following problem:

*Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with PDF
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1, &-1\leq x<0\\
1-x, &0\leq x\leq1\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$
Let $Y=X(X-1)$. Determine the PDF of $Y$.*

I have no idea how I'm supposed to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I found the CDF to be
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x\leq -1\\
\frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{2}, &-1\leq x\leq 0\\
\frac{1}{2}\left(1+2x-x^{2}\right), &0\leq x\leq 1\\
1,&x>1
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Hint: $X$ almost surely takes values from $[-1,1]$. Find $F_X$ where $F_X(t) = \mathbb P(X \le t)$. Then find $F_Y$ where $F_Y(t) = \mathbb P(Y \le t)$.

Hint 2: When $x \in [-1,1]$ then $x(x-1) \in [-\frac{1}{4},2]$, so you only need to find $F_Y(t)$ for $t \in [-\frac{1}{4},2]$. Try to rewrite $F_Y(t)$ in terms of $F_X(s)$ for some $s$ (maybe different than $t$. For example $F_Y(0) = \mathbb P(Y \le 0) = \mathbb P(X(X-1) \le 0 ) = \mathbb P(X \in [0,1]) = F_X(1) - F_X(0-)$. In general case you need to solve inequality $X(X-1) \le t$

Comment: I'll try that out thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-1<x<0 \ y$ varies between $[0,2]$, so by solving $x^2 -x - y= 0$ you need to use the negative root to find the CDF of $Y$:
$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P \bigg(X>\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4y}}{2}\bigg) = \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4y}}{2}}^{0}(1+x)dx  
$$
For $x \in [0,1] y \in [-\frac{1}{4}, 0]$, it's first a decreasing, and then an increasing function, you need to use the second (positive) root. For $x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$,

$$
F_Y(y) = P(X>h^{-1}(y)) = \int_{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4y}}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx
$$
For the third interval, $x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, you need $P(X\leq h^{-1}(y))$

$$
F_Y(y) = P\bigg(X < \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4y}}{2}\bigg) = P(X  \leq h^{-1}(y)) = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{h^{-1}(y)}f(x)dx
$$
In the two last cases $f(x)=1-x$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow.

Comment: @AnastasisGiannikopoulos: apologies, I fixed it

Comment: Oh okay I get it now. Thank you very much.